# Why call verifyDrawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-drawable

Will someone please explain why I would ever call `verifyDrawable` given that it apparently does nothing. For instance, I have a view that is showing its own drawables (not really sure what this means: would all ImageViews qualify?). Since my view is displaying its own drawables, I am supposed to call this method on each drawable? But this method is not a Drawable method, it is a View method. So I am confused. Will someone please explain? I am including the whole source code below

```
/**
 * If your view subclass is displaying its own Drawable objects, it should
 * override this function and return true for any Drawable it is
 * displaying.  This allows animations for those drawables to be
 * scheduled.
 *
 * <p>Be sure to call through to the super class when overriding this
 * function.
 *
 * @param who The Drawable to verify.  Return true if it is one you are
 *            displaying, else return the result of calling through to the
 *            super class.
 *
 * @return boolean If true than the Drawable is being displayed in the
 *         view; else false and it is not allowed to animate.
 *
 * @see #unscheduleDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)
 * @see #drawableStateChanged()
 */
@CallSuper
protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
    return who == mBackground || (mScrollCache != null && mScrollCache.scrollBar == who)
            || (mForegroundInfo != null && mForegroundInfo.mDrawable == who);
}
```

Comment: "I am supposed to call this method on each drawable?" -- according to the first sentence of the code comment, you are supposed to **override** the method.